# How to add css in title

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi  I cann't add CSS class name in category title function. How to add  class name in below function:

```
 <?php the_category(', '); ?> //function return array of category
```

Comment: added a tag.Add some details that make easy understand question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override functionality that already in template,

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L249

You can use the_category filter to hook a callback function like this:

```
add_filter('the_category','add_class_to_category',10,3);

function add_class_to_category( $thelist, $separator, $parents){
    $class_to_add = 'category-class';
    return str_replace('<a href="', '<a class="' . $class_to_add . '" href="', $thelist);
}
```

You have to paste this code into a functions.php

Comment: <?php 
    ! isset ( $loop_first ) and the_category(', ');
    $loop_first = 1;
    ?>             sir how to add css class in this code

Comment: can you please add image what you need to change

Comment: actually i want to add css into the ()  for this by array  <?php the_category();?>  .is it possible?

Comment: the_category doesn't have such parameter

Comment: did you try above thing??

Comment: please see my another answer